# Vim - replace every line matching a pattern with a register

Tags: vim, neovim

Supposed register y is filled with some text. Can I replace every line in a buffer matching some pattern with register y?

I would think it's something like:

```
:g/[pattern]/"yp
```

But that definitely doesn't work (and I knew it wouldn't but tried anyway). Is there a way to do this in one fail swoop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach would be to use [`:s\=`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3as%5c%3d)

```
:%s/.*pattern.*/\=@y
```

With `:global`, you'll need something like (untested)

```
:g/pattern/exe "normal! S\<c-r>y\<esc>"
```

may be the following could work (which I'm not sure as I've changed `p` behaviour in visual mode -> untested)

```
 :g/pattern/normal! V"yp
```

or the following which won't change the default register:

```
 :g/pattern/call setline('.', @y)
```